# The best way to set the opacity of an image in Wand?

Tags: wand

What is the best way to set the opacity of an image in Wand?

I'm using the most recent versions of ImageMagick (7.0.8-27 Q16 x64 2019-02-09) and Wand (0.5.1) on a Windows 7 computer.

I don't want to use [transparent_color()](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.transparent_color).

I want to set the alpha channel of an image for alpha-blended overlaying or compositing.

[transparentize()](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.transparentize) does not set the opacity of an image.  It merely darkens the image.

I've tried the following code, but it produced an error.

```
from wand.image import Image, CHANNELS
from wand.api import library

imageOverlay = Image(filename='mona-lisa.png')
imageOverlay.alpha_channel = 'opaque'
library.MagickSetImageOpacity(imageOverlay.wand, 0.2)
imageOverlay.save(filename='test_transparency.png')
```

> library.MagickSetImageOpacity(wand_imageOverlay.wand, 0.2) TypeError:
>   'NoneType' object is not callable

I've also tried the following code, but it produced an error.

```
from wand.image import Image, CHANNELS
from wand.api import library

imageOverlay = Image(filename='mona-lisa.png')
imageOverlay.alpha_channel = 'opaque'
library.MagickEvaluateImage(imageOverlay.wand, 'multiply', 0.2, CHANNELS['alpha'])
imageOverlay.save(filename='test_transparency.png')
```

> library.MagickEvaluateImage(wand_imageOverlay.wand, 'multiply', 0.2,
>   CHANNEL S['alpha']) ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: : wrong type

In Wand, what's the most compact code for setting every alpha-channel pixel to a certain value (e.g. 0.2)?

Comment: Sorry I do not know wand. But once you have an alpha channel put into your images use the equivalent selecting the alpha channel then using -evaluate set 20% then turn all the channels back on. See http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.1/wand/image.html for example for -evaluate set. In command line, that would be `convert image.png -alpha set -channel a -evaluate set 20% +channel result.png`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to fmw42's comment, now I have a block of Wand code for uniformly setting the pixel values of the alpha channel.

```
from wand.image import Image

imageOverlay = Image(filename='mona-lisa.png')
imageOverlay.alpha_channel = True
imageOverlay.evaluate(operator='set', value=imageOverlay.quantum_range*0.2, channel='alpha')
imageOverlay.save(filename='test_transparency.png')
```

The question has been answered.